# Check if a Facebook user has enabled Login Approvals (security code sent through SMS or mobile app when trying to connect from an unknown device)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-authentication

I've searched Facebook FQL documentation and still cannot find out how, from a Facebook app, it would be possible to check whether a user has enabled SMS code / facebook mobile app code login approval functionality or not (same as google 2 step authentification).

When using "login with facebook" functionality while logging in a sensitive website, it could be useful to get this information, so we can accept "login with facebook" only for the users who have enabled the login approval functionality as extra security layer.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can’t get that info – before you get _any_ info about the user, even their ID, they have to log in first. So even if you _could_ look that info up via their ID, you could only do it after they already logged in.

Comment: And I don’t think that info should be made available to apps anyway (and to my knowledge it isn’t) – that would just make it easier for the _bad guys_ to figure out which users to prefer as targets in their hacking attempts, because they would know which one have “lower” security. So, none of an app’s business IMHO.